# Simultaneously inserting and extending a list?

Tags: python

Is there a better way of simultaneously inserting and extending a list? Here is an ugly example of how I'm currently doing it.  (lets say I want to insert '2.4' and '2.6' after the '2' element):

```
>>> a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> b = a[:a.index('2')+1] + ['2.4', '2.6'] + a[a.index('2'):]
>>> b
<<< ['1', '2', '2.4', '2.6', '3', '4']
```

Comment: Are you trying to maintain the list in sorted order?  If so, that question's been asked.

Comment: Minor pendantic comment, ['1', '2', '2.4', '2.6', '2', '3', '4']
 has a duplicated the '2'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> a
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> i = a.index('2') + 1  # after the item '2'
>>> a[i:i] = ['2.4', '2.6']
>>> a
['1', '2', '2.4', '2.6', '3', '4']
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easily insert a single element using `list.insert(i, x)`, which Python defines as `s[i:i] = [x]`.

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
for elem in reversed(['2.4', '2.6']):
    a.insert(a.index('2')+1, elem))
```

If you want to insert a list, you can make your own function that omits the []:

```
def iextend(lst, i, x):
    lst[i:i] = x

a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
iextend(a, a.index('2')+1, ['2.4', '2.6']
# a  = ['1', '2', '2.4', '2.6', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're doing; if you want to add values, and have the list remain in order, it's cleaner (and probably still faster) to just sort the whole thing:

```
a.extend(['2.4', '2.6'])
a.sort()
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [bisect module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html). I think it does what you want.